# multimech is not recognized on Windows

Tags: python

I just follow up the steps to install multimechanize on Windows, I didn't get errors during the installation, I'm tried with python 2.7 and 2.6... but I'm getting the following error when I tried to create a new project,

C:\multi-mechanize-1.2.0>multimech-newproject msilesMultimech
'multimech-newproject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

is there something else that I need to do or install

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue following these steps

from Python26/Scripts/ I ran the following command

- easy_install pip

Then I ran
- pip install -U multi-mechanize and it works...